# Как сделать однократную подписку на событие?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим есть кнопка, возможно ли повешать на нее событие и что бы из другого места кода другие подписки на это событие не сработали? То есть сработала только одна первая подписка. Или это костыльный метод?

пример:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
 alert("one");
});

$("button").click(function(){
 alert("two");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
click me
</button>
```

нужно чтобы было только сообщение **one** и сработало один раз, т.е снять событие после его выполнения.

Comment: однократная это значит _только один обработчик_? или только одно срабатывание? Добавь пример кода использования с описанием поведения, пока не совсем понятно

Comment: @Grundy одно срабатывание , сейчас код напишу.

Comment: _и что бы из другого места кода другие подписки на это событие не сработали_ - вот эта часть особенно непонятна :-)

Comment: @Grundy добавил пример

Comment: это только кровавым патчингом _addEventListener_ можно. Из коробки не поддерживается. На любой элемент, в любой момент можно добавить обработчик.

Comment: @Grundy , а если применить такой способ это костыль получится?

Comment: это очевидно костыль. и пока непонятно _зачем_ это вообще понадобилось

Comment: даже больше того: таким образом нельзя отловить так называемую _делегацию событий_ когда обработчик вешается на контейнер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если только JS то примерно так.

```
var clickFunction = function (event) {
    window.removeEventListener('click',clickFunction, false );

};
window.addEventListener("click", clickFunction, false);
```

Если jQuery то используй [$.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: там вопрос обновился (добавился пример), ваш ответ делает только половину того что надо

Comment: А почему тебе не удалить все события к елементу ($.unbind()) а потом установить свой.

Comment: например потому, что ты не можешь контролировать когда _кто-то еще_ может добавить обработчик, чтобы вызвать _unbind_. Плюс не решаемая проблема с делегацией события

Comment: ну и я не автор вопроса :-)

Comment: :) Дааа.
Знаю вот такое решение. На элемент `$('button')` устанавливаешь событие onMouseOver. Как событие срабатывает то удаляешь все 'click' события оставляя только свое. Это не решит проблемы полностью, но некоторое решение даст.

Comment: и опять же это не решает проблему делегирования

Comment: Согласен. Но хоть некоторое решение. Может пригодится!